# Postfix: stop all outgoing emails

Tags: postfix

I'd like to configure Postfix to completely disable outgoing emails, of any type. It should  not be possible to send any email from that server.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just preventing mail submission to the reserved tcp ports is easy through different methods - what you should think about is *how* you want to act on violations of that policy. Immediate reject? Deferral? Connection/Execution-Level error before even trying? Should the reason be properly explained to the would-be sender? How would you like to be notified that someone ran into your stopping measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be many ways, including [`smtpd_relay_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions)`=` [`defer_unauth_destination`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#defer_unauth_destination) (without the `permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated` from the default setting).

But you have to keep in mind that Postfix is not the only software that can send mail from the server. Any application could open direct connections to external mail servers on port `25/tcp`. Therefore, you should really do this on the firewall level by rejecting outbound connections to the SMTP port.

Answer (score 4):

you can stop outgoing emails being sent through postfix from your local machine. Simply put the line below into the /etc/postfix/main.cf file.

```
default_transport = error:No outside emails.
```

The variable default_transport specifies which transport is used to deliver non-local mail (default is smtp). With this setting, any outgoing mail will bounce back with the error specified.